# warping and outputting coordinates of GeoTiff data: advice and error checking

Tags: gdal, coordinates, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

So I have a massive TIF file (projected in Lambert azimuthal equal-area), and I'm trying to get lat/lon coordinates for each point of the grid.

My first step is to warp the projection to the WGS84 datum using:

```
>gdalwarp giganticfile.tif warpedcroppedfile.tif -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" -te -120 25 -60 55
```

Then I make that tif file into the following xyz format file:

```
>gdal_translate -of XYZ warpedcroppedfile.tif latlongvalues.dat
```

I can read a manual page as well as anyone else, but I'm new to this, so my two questions are:

1. does anyone have suggestions on how do do this better? I don't have ArcGIS access.
2. How do I error check myself.

I plotted the warped/cropped file, and it looked 'reasonable'(i.e., I could see a map of the US), but I'm doing some numerical analysis with the outputs, and I want to make sure that my data are good. So how do I error check myself? Manually go through the math for a few points?

Comment: Warping a grid is not going to give lonlat points that correspond to the original pixels. Why not xyz out from the original and reproject those? Prob easy enough with command line tools but I usually do this in R so I need to try it first

Comment: In what way will they not correspond to the original pixels? Slight shifts are still ok, but if we are talking about tens of kilometers off of the original point (pixels are at 250m), then there is a problem.

Comment: Warping inherently creates a new grid of points, it's got nothing to do with the original.

Comment: I understand that if I have a 250x250m grid, and I warp the the data to some other projection, I'm going to lose that 'complete' coverage, and the pixels will look different. But still, each value should still correspond to more or less the same location on the surface of the earth, right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Looks good, but you can crop, warp and convert data into XYZ with a single command by addind parameter `-of XYZ` to your gdalwarp command. However, some file formats are not good targets for gdalwarp which must append data to initialized target while the warping process is progressing. Make a trial and test if using tiff as on interim format is faster or not.

2) You can use gdallocationinfo for capturing reference data from the original tiff file.

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 giganticfile.tif x-longitude y-latitude
```